# How can I automate updating excel table and chart data in PowerPoint?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

I have over 127 files to update each month and they have 20 graphs over 6 slides. Each time I open PowerPoint I have to manually click update links. I have to wait for all the links to update and repeat each time. This is a very slow process.

I am looking to see if this can be sped up? I manually also update the 127 excel files to pull in the latest data and save before the PPT step above.

TIA!

Comment: What are these links, and how do they update your graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to open the files (manually, or with VBA), you can simply use [this command to update all OLE links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-updatelinks-method-powerpoint) in the presentation:

```
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
```

Comment: I can open them manually but it takes hours to open and update all of them

Comment: However, if I open all of them and do not update, I can likely run this macro. I would still need to save the file to a video (mp4) to finish. Is there a way to do that in VB?

Comment: @user2332929 that's a new question